# Out of memory exception due to large bitmap size

Tags: android

I have a problem of out of memory due to limited virtual memory heap size.
Here is my code for fetching bitmap from server:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class DrawableManager {

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
private final Map drawableMap;

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private DrawableManager() {
        drawableMap = new HashMap();
    }

    static private DrawableManager  _instance;

    static public DrawableManager getInstance() {
        if(_instance == null) {
            _instance = new DrawableManager();
        }
        return _instance;
    }

    public Bitmap fetchBitmap(final String sURL) {
        if(sURL.length() == 0)
            return null;
        Bitmap bm = (Bitmap) drawableMap.get(sURL);
        if(bm != null) {
            return bm;
        }

        byte[] imageData = ThumbImg(sURL);

        if(imageData == null)
            return null;

        if(imageData.length > 0) {
            bm =  BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0, imageData.length);
            if(bm != null) {
                drawableMap.put(sURL, bm);
            }
            return bm;
        }
        else { 
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void fetchBitmapOnThread(final String sURL, final ImageView imageView) {
        if (drawableMap.containsKey(sURL)) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) drawableMap.get(sURL));
        }

        final Handler handler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message message) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) message.obj);
            }
        };

        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Bitmap bitmap = fetchBitmap(sURL);
                Message message = handler.obtainMessage(1, bitmap);
                handler.sendMessage(message);
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static byte[] ThumbImg(String imgUrl) 
    {

        //first check in the cache, if not available then store in the sd card memory
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            String userAgent = null;

            try
            {
                URL url = new URL(imgUrl);
                connection = ( HttpURLConnection ) url.openConnection();
                 if(userAgent != null) {
                     connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", userAgent);
                 }
                 connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
                 connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
                    int CHUNKSIZE = 8192;        //size of fixed chunks
                int BUFFERSIZE = 1024;       //size of reading buffer


                 int bytesRead = 0;
                 byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFERSIZE];   //initialize buffer
                 byte[] fixedChunk = new byte[CHUNKSIZE]; //initialize 1st chunk
                 ArrayList<byte[]> BufferChunkList = new ArrayList<byte[]>(); // List of chunk data
                 int spaceLeft = CHUNKSIZE;
                 int chunkIndex = 0;

                 DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(connection.getInputStream() );

                 while( ( bytesRead = in.read( buffer ) ) != -1 ) { //loop until the DataInputStream is completed
                     if(bytesRead > spaceLeft) {
                         //copy to end of current chunk
                         System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, fixedChunk, chunkIndex, spaceLeft);
                         BufferChunkList.add(fixedChunk);

                         //create a new chunk, and fill in the leftover
                         fixedChunk = new byte[CHUNKSIZE];
                         chunkIndex = bytesRead - spaceLeft;
                         System.arraycopy(buffer, spaceLeft, fixedChunk, 0, chunkIndex);
                     } else {
                         //plenty of space, just copy it in
                         System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, fixedChunk, chunkIndex, bytesRead);
                         chunkIndex = chunkIndex + bytesRead;
                     }
                     spaceLeft = CHUNKSIZE - chunkIndex;
                 }

                 if (in != null) {
                     in.close();
                 }

                 // copy it all into one big array
                 int responseSize = (BufferChunkList.size() * CHUNKSIZE) + chunkIndex;  
                 Log.d("response size",""+responseSize);
                 byte[] responseBody = new byte[responseSize];
                 int index = 0;
                 for(byte[] b : BufferChunkList) {
                     System.arraycopy(b, 0, responseBody, index, CHUNKSIZE);
                     index = index + CHUNKSIZE;
                 }
                 System.arraycopy(fixedChunk, 0, responseBody, index, chunkIndex);

                return responseBody;                     


            }catch(SocketTimeoutException se)
            {

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally
            {
                if(connection!=null)
                connection.disconnect();
            }

        return null;
    }

}
```

This is the code that I am using, this works fine with smaller images but not for large images. What is the problem  and to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: http://codingaffairs.blogspot.com/2016/07/processing-bitmap-and-memory-management.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its not always a good idea to store bitmaps in memory. If you really want to do so then try using SoftReference for your map. [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945201/android-image-cache)

make your map's value argument as `SoftReference<Bitmap>`. Then while searching in the map use this code snippet

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class DrawableManager {

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
private final Map<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>> drawableMap;

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private DrawableManager() {
        drawableMap = new HashMap<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>>();
    }

    static private DrawableManager  _instance;

    static public DrawableManager getInstance() {
        if(_instance == null) {
            _instance = new DrawableManager();
        }
        return _instance;
    }

    public Bitmap fetchBitmap(final String sURL) {
        if(sURL.length() == 0)
            return null;
        Bitmap bm = null;
            SoftReference<Bitmap> reference = drawbaleM.get(imagePath);                  
            if(reference != null) bm = reference.get();
            if(bm != null) {
             return bm;
            }

        byte[] imageData = ThumbImg(sURL);

        if(imageData == null)
            return null;

        if(imageData.length > 0) {
            bm =  BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0, imageData.length);
            if(bm != null) {
                drawableMap.put(sURL, bm);
            }
            return bm;
        }
        else { 
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void fetchBitmapOnThread(final String sURL, final ImageView imageView) {
        if (drawableMap.containsKey(sURL)) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) drawableMap.get(sURL));
        }

        final Handler handler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message message) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) message.obj);
            }
        };

        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Bitmap bitmap = fetchBitmap(sURL);
                Message message = handler.obtainMessage(1, bitmap);
                handler.sendMessage(message);
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static byte[] ThumbImg(String imgUrl) 
    {

        //first check in the cache, if not available then store in the sd card memory
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            String userAgent = null;

            try
            {
                URL url = new URL(imgUrl);
                connection = ( HttpURLConnection ) url.openConnection();
                 if(userAgent != null) {
                     connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", userAgent);
                 }
                 connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
                 connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
                    int CHUNKSIZE = 8192;        //size of fixed chunks
                int BUFFERSIZE = 1024;       //size of reading buffer


                 int bytesRead = 0;
                 byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFERSIZE];   //initialize buffer
                 byte[] fixedChunk = new byte[CHUNKSIZE]; //initialize 1st chunk
                 ArrayList<byte[]> BufferChunkList = new ArrayList<byte[]>(); // List of chunk data
                 int spaceLeft = CHUNKSIZE;
                 int chunkIndex = 0;

                 DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(connection.getInputStream() );

                 while( ( bytesRead = in.read( buffer ) ) != -1 ) { //loop until the DataInputStream is completed
                     if(bytesRead > spaceLeft) {
                         //copy to end of current chunk
                         System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, fixedChunk, chunkIndex, spaceLeft);
                         BufferChunkList.add(fixedChunk);

                         //create a new chunk, and fill in the leftover
                         fixedChunk = new byte[CHUNKSIZE];
                         chunkIndex = bytesRead - spaceLeft;
                         System.arraycopy(buffer, spaceLeft, fixedChunk, 0, chunkIndex);
                     } else {
                         //plenty of space, just copy it in
                         System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, fixedChunk, chunkIndex, bytesRead);
                         chunkIndex = chunkIndex + bytesRead;
                     }
                     spaceLeft = CHUNKSIZE - chunkIndex;
                 }

                 if (in != null) {
                     in.close();
                 }

                 // copy it all into one big array
                 int responseSize = (BufferChunkList.size() * CHUNKSIZE) + chunkIndex;  
                 Log.d("response size",""+responseSize);
                 byte[] responseBody = new byte[responseSize];
                 int index = 0;
                 for(byte[] b : BufferChunkList) {
                     System.arraycopy(b, 0, responseBody, index, CHUNKSIZE);
                     index = index + CHUNKSIZE;
                 }
                 System.arraycopy(fixedChunk, 0, responseBody, index, chunkIndex);

                return responseBody;                     


            }catch(SocketTimeoutException se)
            {

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally
            {
                if(connection!=null)
                connection.disconnect();
            }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Please note this doesnot guarantee relief from OOM. It is not always a good idea to show large bitmaps.

Another option you can go after is use [BitmapFactory.Options inSampleSize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize) argument

Comment: @frieza: but where and how to use SoftReferences in my code. Can you please explain

Comment: @frieza: Can you please edit your sample code in mine code as this is giving error on my side while making changes according your sample code

Comment: @frieza: But it is showing error in drawbleM.get() as not able to cast in sofwarereferense

Comment: As I have also used this as :  private DrawableManager() { drawableMap = new HashMap(); } where DrawableManager is class and calling constructor

Comment: Sorry but what you are saying is not clear. Can you post your code

Comment: @frieza: Did you find any solution to this problem as I have edited my code

Comment: @frieza: Using  BitmapFactory.Options inSampleSize reduces the quality of image as it streches the image ......how can i regain the original look through this option

Comment: Not possible, you need to compromise with something when working with large bitmaps. By the way did SoftReference work to some extent ?

Comment: @frieza:while adding your code provided above.....It is giving error in this line                               imageView.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) drawableMap.get(sURL)); as can't convert softwareRefernce to bitmap

Comment: @frieza: showing error at most places where used bm as to convert in SoftwareRefernces

Comment: dude when you do `drawableMap.get(sURL)` it returns a `SoftReference` for a bitmap. From that `SoftReference` object (lets call it `reference` and please check for null) you need to call `reference.get()` which will return you the bitmap. You can't directly cast a SoftRefernce object to bitmap

Comment: @frieza: how to cast drawableM from SoftwareReference to bitmap

Comment: see this code `Bitmap bm = null;
            SoftReference<Bitmap> reference = drawbaleM.get(imagePath);                  
            if(reference != null) bm = reference.get();
            if(bm != null) {
             return bm;
            }`

Comment: drawableM is a HashMap, you can't cast HashMap to Bitmap. see my previous comment carefully. It clearly says that when you call the get(sURL) method on your map, it returns you a SoftRefernce object. You can consider this object as a container for your bitmap. call the get() method on this SoftRefernce object to get your bitmap. I have no other better way to explain this further. Also you can look for Softrefernce documentation. Also please see this link for further clarification http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/XmlAdapters/src/com/example/android/xmladapters/ImageDownloader.html

Comment: @frieza: ok! thanks for your so much help. I hope this will help me out of my problem

Comment: Dalvik's garbage collector is very eager to collect soft referenced objects, so Google recommends using their LruCache instead.

Answer (score 0):

BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray() creates the bitmap data in the Native heap, not the VM heap. See [BitmapFactory OOM driving me nuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955410/bitmapfactory-oom-driving-me-nuts/) for details.

You could monitor the Native heap (as per [BitmapFactory OOM driving me nuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955410/bitmapfactory-oom-driving-me-nuts/)) and downsample if you're running short of space.

Comment: Can you please tell me where and how to include this sample in my code (as shown above) to run

Comment: Based on the SO response linked, since Honeycomb Bitmap _are_ allocated on the VM heap. So this is not a solution anymore if your minSDK is more than 13