# Memory error while using bitmap image in android

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory, android-image

I am using a large bitmap image for my application. While using the application, I get an out-of-memory error. My question is: how do I reduce the image size without reducing the resolution in android? Is there any other way to avoid an out-of-memory error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use softreference for your bitmap here is link that might be helpful for you

[Out of memory exception due to large bitmap size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321579/out-of-memory-exception-due-to-large-bitmap-size)