# Using Android's System Cache

Tags: android, image, caching, download, system

I would like to use Android's system cache when downloading images as per these previous instructions: [android system cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945201/android-image-cache/3893959#3893959).  I was able to get the following code working but the log statements are telling me that the images are never being read from the cache.

```
try {
    //url = new URL("http://some.url.com/retrieve_image.php?user=" + username);
    URL url = new URL("http://some.url.com/prof_pics/b4fe7bdfa174ff372c9f26ce6f78f19c.png");
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    connection.setUseCaches(true);
    Object response = connection.getContent();
    if (response instanceof Bitmap) {
        Log.i("CHAT", "this is a bitmap");
        current_image.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) response);
    }
    else {
        Log.i("CHAT", "this is not a bitmap");
        Log.i("CHAT", response.toString());
        InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        current_image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis));
    }
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have tried two different types of requests, one is to go through a PHP script that returns the image and another that is directly accessing the image file.  I refresh the same image multiple times in a row and it never seems to get cached.  For the direct  image access, I get:

```
05-31 23:45:12.177 I/CHAT    ( 2995): this is not a bitmap
05-31 23:45:12.177 I/CHAT    ( 2995): org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.FixedLengthInputStream@40c1c660`
```

For the indirect image access, I consistently get:

```
05-31 23:45:14.550 I/CHAT    ( 2995): this is not a bitmap
05-31 23:45:14.550 I/CHAT    ( 2995): org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.ChunkedInputStream@40c02448
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a better way to do it.  If anyone else is having trouble after following the link [android system cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945201/android-image-cache/3893959#3893959), use this [Google developer's blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html) instead.  The source code in that blog post is designed for a ListView but I am using it for all image retrievals.  It downloads the image in an AsyncTask, puts a temporary image while downloading, and *has an image cache*.  This last part is listed as a "Future Item" in the blog post, but if you download the source code, the cache is implemented.  I had to modify the code slightly because the AndroidHttpClient isn't supported in 2.1.  I switched it to a URL connection.  So far, this looks to be a great image downloader class.  Let's just hope it doesn't impact our already struggling memory management issues.