# how to overcome "bitmap size exceeds VM budget " error?

Tags: android, bitmap

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget.
```

i am updating images to a gridview from internet using this imageloader class.some times i have to download around 1000 images but getting the same error.
please help me for the same.

```
  public class ImageLoader {


   public static  HashMap<String, Bitmap> cache=new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();

   private File cacheDir;
   int i=0;
   File f;
   BitmapDrawable b;
    public ImageLoader(Context context){
        //Make the background thead low priority. This way it will not affect the UI performance
        photoLoaderThread.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY-1);

       GridViewConfig.clearFilelist();
       GridViewConfig.file_list=new ArrayList<String>();


        //Find the dir to save cached images
        if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
            cacheDir=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"LazyList");
        else
            cacheDir=context.getCacheDir();
        if(!cacheDir.exists())
            cacheDir.mkdirs();
    }

    final int stub_id=R.drawable.imagelistback_106x133;
    public void DisplayImage(String url, Activity activity, ImageView imageView)
    {

        if(cache.containsKey(url))
        {

           /* if(Common.isgallery)
            {
            b=null;
            b=new BitmapDrawable(cache.get(url));
            Bitmap bb=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(cache.get(url), 300, 300, true);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bb);
            bb.recycle();
            }
            else
            {*/

                 imageView.setImageBitmap(cache.get(url));
           /* }*/
        }
        else
        {
            //Toast.makeText(activity, "ELSE in dISPLAY iMAGES", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            queuePhoto(url, activity, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }   



    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, Activity activity, ImageView imageView)
    {
        //This ImageView may be used for other images before. So there may be some old tasks in the queue. We need to discard them. 
        photosQueue.Clean(imageView);
        PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
            photosQueue.photosToLoad.push(p);
            photosQueue.photosToLoad.notifyAll();
        }

        //start thread if it's not started yet
        if(photoLoaderThread.getState()==Thread.State.NEW)
            photoLoaderThread.start();
    }
    public void Createfile(String url)
    {
        String filename=String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
        f=new File(cacheDir, filename);
        GridViewConfig.file_list.add(f.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) 
    {

        //I identify images by hashcode. Not a perfect solution, good for the demo.
        String filename=String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
        //String filename=GridViewConfig.sku_list.get(i);
        File f=new File(cacheDir, filename);
        GridViewConfig.file_list.add(f.getAbsolutePath());
        /*if(Common.firstLoading)
        {
        GridViewConfig.file_list.add(f.getAbsolutePath());
        i++;
        Log.v("gooooooooogle file list", "file list size "+i);

        }*/
        //from SD cache
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if(b!=null)
            return b;

        //from web
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap=null;
            InputStream is=new URL(url).openStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
           return null;
        }
    }

    //decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
        try {
            //decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE=50;
            int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
            int scale=1;
            while(true){
                if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp/=2;
                height_tmp/=2;
                scale++;
            }
            Log.v("", "Scale"+scale);
            //decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
        return null;
    }

    //Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad
    {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
            url=u; 
            imageView=i;
        }
    }

    PhotosQueue photosQueue=new PhotosQueue();

    public void stopThread()
    {
        photoLoaderThread.interrupt();
    }

    //stores list of photos to download
    class PhotosQueue
    {
        private Stack<PhotoToLoad> photosToLoad=new Stack<PhotoToLoad>();

        //removes all instances of this ImageView
        public void Clean(ImageView image)
        {
            for(int j=0 ;j<photosToLoad.size();){
                if(photosToLoad.get(j).imageView==image)
                    photosToLoad.remove(j);
                else
                    ++j;
            }
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            try {
                while(true)
                {
                    //thread waits until there are any images to load in the queue
                    if(photosQueue.photosToLoad.size()==0)
                        synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
                            photosQueue.photosToLoad.wait();
                        }
                    if(photosQueue.photosToLoad.size()!=0)
                    {
                        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
                        synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
                            photoToLoad=photosQueue.photosToLoad.pop();
                        }
                        Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
                        cache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
                        if(((String)photoToLoad.imageView.getTag()).equals(photoToLoad.url)){
                            BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad.imageView);
                            Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
                            a.runOnUiThread(bd);
                        }
                    }
                    if(Thread.interrupted())
                        break;
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                //allow thread to exit
            }
        }
    }

    PhotosLoader photoLoaderThread=new PhotosLoader();

    //Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
    {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        ImageView imageView;
        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, ImageView i)
        {
            bitmap=b;
            imageView=i;
        }
        public void run()
        {
            if(bitmap!=null)
                /*if(Common.isgallery)
                {
                    b=null;
                    b=new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
                    Bitmap bit=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 300, 300, true);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bit);
                    bit.recycle();
                }
                else
                {*/
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                /*}*/
            else
                imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        //clear memory cache
        cache.clear();

        //clear SD cache
        File[] files=cacheDir.listFiles();
        for(File f:files)
            f.delete();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest:

- use `SoftReference<Bitmap>` or `WeakReference<Bitmap>` instead of simple Bitmap in `cache`. That way You won't face OOM;
- use [options for decoding](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html) (as suggested by Awais Tariq) - [inSampleSize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize) option gives nice improvement on memory (seems already done in Your code);
- maintain cache on sd card for downloaded images. Please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945201/android-image-caching) for additional options (seems already done in Your code).

Comment: Sandrstar's suggestions are excellent. I would also add the following:
- opt for a collection of SoftReference<Bitmap> since GC will only free these objects at the last moment before a OOME would occur
- take a look at LRU cache for more control over which items get removed and when (essentially uses a LinkedHashMap)

Answer (score 0):

Use Bitmap Options to assign bitmaps.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html

Further try to call garbage collector manually (System.gc();) as the bitmap memory is not released untill unless application is closed..

Answer (score 0):

You are using too much objects of bitmap, but not releasing them after there work is done.
So please call **bitmapObj.recycle();** when you are done with particular bitmap object.

It'll release the memory occupied by the that object.

Answer (score 0):

the same problem i have face and i have the permanent solution for this:

first that whatever image you are using you need to scale them so that it will consume less memory and your "OutOfMemoryError" will resolve.

example: 
visit this link

http://android-solution-sample.blogspot.com/search/label/Bitmap%20out%20of%20memory

after decoding you should use the image so that it consume less memory.