# caching disk image

Tags: android, caching

I am trying to use a disk cache (not a memory cache) so i download my images from an urls and put it in a grid view. I want to download my images only one time.

I found this example (bitmapFun) in google site: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

I found this example a bit complicated.
There are many objects in util package (AsyncTask, DiskLruCache, ImageCache, ImageFetcher, ImageResizer, ImageWorker, Utils)

Is there a way or a tutorial that show how can i use a disk Lru cache without using all those object.
I don't want to resize my image and i was not able to remove ImageResizer class.

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945201/android-image-caching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have good answer :[Android image caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945201/android-image-caching). Quotation :

"Consider using [Universal Image Loader library](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) by Sergey Tarasevich. It comes with:

```
//Multithread image loading. It lets you can define the thread pool size
//Image caching in memory, on device's file sytem and SD card.
//Possibility to listen to loading progress and loading events
```

Universal Image Loader allows detailed cache management for downloaded images, with the following cache configurations:

```
UsingFreqLimitedMemoryCache: //The least frequently used bitmap is deleted when the cache size limit is exceeded.
LRULimitedMemoryCache: //The least recently used bitmap is deleted when the cache size limit is exceeded.
FIFOLimitedMemoryCache: //The FIFO rule is used for deletion when the cache size limit is exceeded.
LargestLimitedMemoryCache: //The largest bitmap is deleted when the cache size limit is exceeded.
LimitedAgeMemoryCache: //The Cached object is deleted when its age exceeds defined value.
WeakMemoryCache: //A memory cache with only weak references to bitmaps.
```

A simple usage example:

```
ImageView imageView = groupView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
String imageUrl = "http://domain.com/image.png"; 

ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));
imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrl, imageView);
```

This example uses the default `UsingFreqLimitedMemoryCache`.