# Setting image from url

Tags: android

I have an image view in my Android app, where I have to set a simple image from url. I tried the below code, but it doesn't set the image from url.

```
try {
        URL url = new URL("https://drive.google.com/...");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap teamBmpImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
        teamImgView.setImageBitmap(teamBmpImage);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

Could someone guide me to achieve this please?

**UPDATED CODE: Which gives Nullpointer exception**

```
public class AboutActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    ImageView teamImgView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);

        teamImgView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.teamImageView);
        new DownloadImageTask(teamImgView).execute("http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/examples/strawberry.jpg");
    }

    class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;

        public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            //pd.show();
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            //pd.dismiss();
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best method to download image from url in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18210700/best-method-to-download-image-from-url-in-android)

Comment: No solution from this link worked out, that's why created new question

Comment: There actually are several good tips in the answers, if you tried those you should mention it in your question and specify what went wrong

Comment: I tried the async task samples, in my code throwing error as: 04-27 03:38:43.933    3034-3034/com.me.xyz.abc E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.me.xyz.abc, PID: 3034
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.me.xyz.abc.AboutActivity$DownloadImageTask.onPostExecute(AboutActivity.java:170)
            at com.me.xyz.abc.AboutActivity$DownloadImageTask.onPostExecute(AboutActivity.java:139)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)

Comment: Well that is not very helpful without the code. There is a `NullPointerException` on line 170 of `AboutActivity`. Image downloading is quite complex task on android, I would suggest to use some library instead of handling it yourself if you don't know what you are doing.

Comment: I updated my full code in the question.

Comment: This code works for me, check `this.findViewById(R.id.teamImageView);` for null, it's the only thing that could cause the exception

Comment: Ok, I'll check that.

Comment: That was causing the issue, it works now thank you very much

Comment: I have an image from google drive. This link doesn't need any login authentication. it will work to anyone to download the image. When I am giving this url, the same code doesn't download and display image in imageview. https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0BzcFuGIeWflwZ25aeDdiVkJfNzA

Comment: That is not a link to the image, [this is](https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0BzcFuGIeWflwZ25aeDdiVkJfNzA). You have to remove `export=download` parameter from the URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are executing your code on the MainThread, which leads to a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` in android. Try to execute your code asynchronous like in the example below

```
new AsyncTask<String, Integer, Bitmap>() {

@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(params[0]);
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bm) {
    ImageView teamImgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.teamImageView);
    teamImgView.setImageBitmap(bm);
}
}.execute("https://drive.google.com/uc?....");
```

Comment: have you added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` to your manifest? and can you post your stacktrace?

Comment: Internet persmission is already there, because I'm using it for some other purposes.

Comment: Can you pls try this sample with this link, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/examples/strawberry.jpg

Comment: Did so, works fine. In your comment on your question you said that you get a nullpointer in line 170 (in onPostExecute). How does your code in line 170 looks like? When you followed my example either your ImageView is null (maybe you have set the wrong xml file as your contentView) or the bitmap is null, due to a exception in doInBackground.

Comment: I've tried your code from your update and it works with the strawberry image, but not with your https google drive link. In both cases the app does not crash. Btw line 170 is commented out, so there cant occure a nullpointer. Guess i need to see the stacktrace

Comment: Can you try with this url please? https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0BzcFuGIeWflwVUlqNWRzWWwwdVk

Comment: For me its crashing on emulator even with strawberry image. I am testing on Genymotion emulator.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76344/discussion-between-doncalzone-and-stella).

Comment: I have an image from google drive. This link doesn't need any login authentication. it will work to anyone to download the image. When I am giving this url, the same code doesn't download and display image in imageview. https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0BzcFuGIeWflwZ25aeDdiVkJfNzA

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Picasso library](http://square.github.io/picasso/) and [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-working-with-picasso--cms-22149) is a detailed tutorial on how to do this.

This is very simple example usage

```
Picasso.with(activityContext)
    .load("https://drive.google.com/uc?....")
    .placeholder(R.drawable.image_name)
    .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

As bojan says you can use Picasso library wich handles many common pitfalls of image loading on Android.

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://myurl/myImage.png").into(imageView);
```

[Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Anyway, check out this threat too :)

[How to load an ImageView by URL in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Try following this link:
http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/11/android-volley-url-imageview.html

This will help you to load your image using Volley library which will do all the networking stuff on networking thread and set your image on main UI thread. It has also the LRUCache part which you can skip if you want.