# Each button opens new activity

Tags: android, url

Each button opens new class, then in that class i want to load a image from a url but, im a begginer and i cant do the url code can you help me?

this is my code with buttons :

**MainActivity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    OnClickButtonListener();
}

public void OnClickButtonListener() {
    button_lb1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_lubri);
    button_lb1.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
    );
    button_lb2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_lubri2);
    button_lb2.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
    );
    button_lb3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_lubri3);
    button_lb3.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FourthActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
    );
    button_cf = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_combri);
    button_cf.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FifthActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
    );
    button_dp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_dp);
    button_dp.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SixthActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
    );
    button_tp= (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_tp);
    button_tp.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SeventhActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
    );
    button_cal= (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_cal);
    button_cal.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EighthActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
    );
}
```

Then i want to load url in the open activity.

Comment: Possible duplicates : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18210700/best-method-to-download-image-from-url-in-android

Comment: Do you want to show a `Web Page/HTML` content in the page?

Comment: No i just want the image in the acitivity

Comment: I dont want to download i just want to load.

Comment: Maybe you can use Glide or Picasso library to load the image in Imageview from url

Comment: I just want the image to appears in the opened activity when i click the button :()

Answer (score 0):

Try Glide to show image.

Here is [link](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

In case link is down then use below code.

Put Below code in Gradle

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral() // jcenter() works as well because it pulls from Maven     Central
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
}
```

Put below code in Activity

```
// For showing simply.
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);

Glide.with(this).load("your_url").into(imageView);
```

If you want to give a place holder

```
 Glide
.with(this)
.load(your_url)
.centerCrop()
.placeholder(R.drawable.place_holder_image)
.crossFade()
.into(imageView);
```

Comment: Where i put this i didnt understand it // For showing simply.
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);

Glide.with(this).load("your_url").into(imageView);

Comment: You can put it at `onCreate()` or `onResume()`

Comment: I started android a week ago bro i cant get it sorry :(

Comment: Then you should learn the components of Android and Life Cycle of Activity.