# Downloading Image Via AsyncTask and displaying it in an Imageview without storing in sdcard

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progress-bar

I want to download an image via `AsyncTask` and want to display it in an `ImageView` I am able to do it normally but I also want to show the progress to the user and do all this without having to store the file in the SDcard.

Here is what I have done so far.

```
class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

/**
 * Before starting background thread
 * Show Progress Bar Dialog
 * */
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    showDialog(progress_bar_type);
}

/**
 * Downloading file in background thread
 * */
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
    int count;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
        URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
        conection.connect();
        // getting file length
        int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

        // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

        // Output stream to write file
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/downloadedfile.jpg");

        byte data[] = new byte[1024];

        long total = 0;

        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;
            // publishing the progress....
            // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
            publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));

            // writing data to file
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }

        // flushing output
        output.flush();

        // closing streams
        output.close();
        input.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * Updating progress bar
 * */
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
    // setting progress percentage
    pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
}

/**
 * After completing background task
 * Dismiss the progress dialog
 * **/
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
    dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);

    // Displaying downloaded image into image view
    // Reading image path from sdcard
    String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/downloadedfile.jpg";
    // setting downloaded into image view
    my_image.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(imagePath));
}

}
```

Comment: Can you explain what's the matter with your  code ?

Comment: @L.Swifter If i save downloaded image locally then everthing works fine but if i use a bitmap instead then the progres bar works fine but the image doesn't show up

Comment: you should use `ByteArrayOutputStream` and `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray` for your purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to download image locally, you should use `ByteArrayOutputStream` instead of `FileOutputStream`.

And this is the key code:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

byte data[] = new byte[1024];
long total = 0;
while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
    total += count;
    publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));

    outputStream.write(data, 0, count);
}

//after downloading the image
byte[] imageData = outputStream.toByteArray();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0, imageData.length);
my_image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

I didn't test it, but I believe this can help you.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked like a charm.(Cannot upvote because of lack of reputations :( )

Comment: happy to help   :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)** instead:

```
Glide.with(this).load("http://server.com/image.jpg").into(imageView);
```

Comment: Thank you for letting us know about this library

Answer (score 0):

reference [Best method to download image from url in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18210700/best-method-to-download-image-from-url-in-android)

```
private Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url) {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            URL uri = new URL(url);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) uri.openConnection();

            int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                return null;
            }

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            if (inputStream != null) {

                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                return bitmap;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("URLCONNECTIONERROR", e.toString());
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error downloading image from " + url);
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();

            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I am doing the same thing but I also have to display the progress to user and there I am facing problem.

Comment: you can use createTempFile, or write file in external/internal dirctory