# Not able to Load Image from Server in android

Tags: java, android

Here I am trying to download a image from server. But it is always throwing Exception. Can any One tell me Why it is Happening and what will be the Correct way?

```
 public static String getBitmap(String url) throws IOException {

        InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
        Bitmap bmp= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        byte[] b=stream.toByteArray();
        String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);


        is.close();
        return encoded;


}
```

Comment: paste the exception that you are getting

Comment: What exception are you getting?? Use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18210700/best-method-to-download-image-from-url-in-android/18211171#18211171)

Comment: can you post the stack trace of your exception?

Comment: Its a better option to use `Picasso` or `Glide` library for loading server image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this functions get bitmap and download the bitmap

```
Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapfromUrl(imageurl);
imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

SaveImage(bitmap);

public Bitmap getBitmapfromUrl(String imageUrl) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return bitmap;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;

    }
}

private void SaveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {

    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");
    myDir.mkdirs();
    Random generator = new Random();
    int n = 10000;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);
    String fname = "Image-" + n;
    File file = new File(myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists()) file.delete();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And Add this permision in your manifest file

Comment: @rashmi ranjan please check my answer. getimage in url and save image easily

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Glide` or `Picasso` image processing library.

1. here is Glide demo

> ```
> Glide.with(this).load(YourImageURL)
>                 .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
>                  .into(Imageview);
> ```

and add this dependency in gradle.

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

you can also set placeholder while image loading. its like `alt` attribute in html

```
Glide.with(this).load(YourImageURL)
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.backimage)
                    .into(Imageview);
```

2. Here is Picasso demo

> ```
>    Picasso.with(context).load(url).placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
>         .error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error)
>         .into(imageView);
> ```

and add this dependency:

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

these lib also provide `cache feature` so you don't need to load second time.

Comment: `But it is always throwing Exception. Can any One tell me Why it is Happening and what will be the Correct way?` You did not answer the questions. Your answer is not an answer but an advise.

Answer (score 0):

Call this function from your activity and get inputStream. After getting inputStream (Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.decodeStream(inputStream));

```
private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String urlString) throws IOException
    {
    InputStream in = null;
    int response = -1;

    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

    if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection)) throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");

    try{
    HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
    httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
    httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
    httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    httpConn.connect();

    response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
    if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
    in = httpConn.getInputStream();
    }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    throw new IOException("Error connecting");
    }
    return in;
    }
```