# Sony Sony Camera Remote API beta SDK Transferring images for RX100IV

Tags: api, sdk, camera, sony

I am developing remote functions for the Sony RX100 IV. One of the requirements is to download the images wirelessly. I am able to download a small resolution image from the Still Capture api. However, I am unable to use any of the APIs for transferring images. Is the functionality available for the RX100IV, and if so, how should I enable it? The API reference is not clear on this.

Answer (score 2):

If for instance you use the actTakePicture endpoint it will return the url to the picture you have taken. From there you can download the picture through the url. Because the Camera API is a web api we are not able to create a function to assist you with image download, but depending on your programming language you should be able to run a quick search to see how to download the image over a url. For instance here is a link showing how to download an image over a url with Android:

[Best method to download image from url in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18210700/best-method-to-download-image-from-url-in-android)

Also you can use the getContentList endpoint to get a list of the items already on the camera and then download it. Here is a link to a post that talks more about how to use this endPoint:

[Using Sony Camera Remote API 2.4 can't get "avContent service" for Sony camera A6300](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45736605/using-sony-camera-remote-api-2-4-cant-get-avcontent-service-for-sony-camera-a/45993859#45993859)