# Download Google Plus profile Image in android locally

Tags: android, google-plus, image-uploading

I am facing issue for downloading image of google plus

1) Sign up via Google 
2) Got response of profile image url

now i want to download that image in android for upload to server
please help for it

Comment: Show some of your code please how you are applying download process ?

Comment: (1) Where is code, (2) Where is error log?

Comment: have you got the url of profile pic

Comment: https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-5GuNWLhTRi0/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAw/Wzy0ZQRsJ-0/photo.jpg THIS IS IMAGE URL FROM GOOGLE RESPONSE

Answer (score 0):

If you use firebase to log in, when you are signed, you can have the profile image via:

```
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

Uri imageUri = auth.getCurrentUser().getPhotoUrl();
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
```

Comment: I am going to save image of google Plus (URL IS https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-5GuNWLhTRi0/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAw/Wzy0ZQRsJ-0/photo.jpg)

Comment: Then your question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18210700/best-method-to-download-image-from-url-in-android https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549421/how-to-download-and-save-an-image-in-android ...

Comment: not work for google plus image download it return blank response

Comment: I can see your image without being logged. To download it, it's just a classic http get. I think nobody can help you more if you don't post your code.